# How to convert Get-ItemProperty from registry to C# registry

Tags: c#, registry

I get the ouput after running the command given below

Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ExchangeServer\v*\Watson *

But after running this code given below in C#

var value = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ExchangeServer\v*\Watson", "*", RegistryOptions.None);

I am getting default but not actual value.

Can anyone please let me know how can i get the value because the above code does not produce result.
I can also use powershell inside C# if not possible with Registry.

Comment: You're being told that your Registry key name is wrong. Have you actually looked in the Registry to see whether there's a key with that path? The issue looks rather obvious.

Comment: ok got it we have to use HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE instead of HKLM but still how can we handle star * because it will produce no result

Comment: Is the asterisk a wildcard? I'm not aware of any way built into .NET to do a wildcard search so you'd have to use some logic. Get a `RegistryKey` for the level above, call `GetSubKeyNames`, filter that list as required and then query all matches separately. You could use LINQ to make it more succinct.